# Rotate and Scale at same time

Tags: css, css-animations

Iam trying to rotate an element once, but scale the element back and forth in an infinite loop. However, when I chain the two animations, only the last one runs. How do I make two different animations to work together?

```css
 .shape{
            width:100px;
            height:50px;
            background-color: brown;
        }

        .ani1{
            animation:  scale 2s linear infinite alternate, rotate 5s ease forwards;
        }
        @keyframes rotate {
            0%{
                transform: rotate(0deg);
            }
            100%{
                transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }
 
        @keyframes scale {
            0%{
                transform: scale(1)
            }
            100%{
                transform: scale(2)
            }
        }
```

```html
    <div class="shape ani1"></div>
```

Comment: _"only the last one runs"_ - no, that is not what is happening. Your second one is manipulating the _same_ CSS property, that the first one manipulates - `transform`. If you were to apply these two transformations "static", would you write `transform: rotate(360deg); transform: scale(2);` in your stylesheet? No of course you would not, because the second time you specify a value for the property, it would overwrite the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On modern browsers CSS property scale is implemented so you could keep your current structure but use that instead of transform.

```css
 .shape{
            width:100px;
            height:50px;
            background-color: brown;
        }

        .ani1{
            animation:  scale 2s linear infinite alternate, rotate 5s ease forwards;
        }
        @keyframes rotate {
            0%{
                transform: rotate(0deg);
            }
            100%{
                transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }
 
        @keyframes scale {
            0%{
               scale: 1;
            }
            100%{
               scale: 2;


            }
        }
```

```html
    <div class="shape ani1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired effect of rotating the element once and then scaling it back and forth in an infinite loop, you need to make a few adjustments to your CSS and animation definitions. One way to accomplish this is by using keyframes for both the rotation and scaling animations and then combining them in a single animation definition. Here's the updated CSS code:

```
.shape {
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
background-color: brown;
animation: rotateAndScale 7s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotateAndScale {
0%, 100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
}
50% {
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(2);
}
}
```

Comment: Wont both rotate and scale happen infinite times in this solution? It should rotate only once